# How to filter(extract) objects in an array based on their similarity in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have an array of some objects and I want to somehow organize them

Here is my Array in JavaScript :

```
  doctors =       [
  {"prop":"A","hour":"08:00"},
  {"prop":"A","hour":"08:00"},
  {"prop":"A","hour":"08:00"},
  {"prop":"A","hour":"08:00"},
  {"prop":"A","hour":"08:00"},
  {"prop":"A","hour":"08:00"},
  {"prop":"B","hour":"08:00"},
  {"prop":"B","hour":"08:00"},
  {"prop":"B","hour":"08:00"},
  {"prop":"C","hour":"08:00"},
  {"prop":"C","hour":"08:00"}       ]
```

This array comes from an ajax call from my back-end(PHP) and I want to change it to be like this :

```
   doctors = [
{"prop":"A",
"hour":"10:00"
"hour":"12:00"
"hour":"23:00"
"hour":"12:00"
"hour":"02:00"
"hour":"01:00"
},

{"prop":"B",
"hour":"18:00"
"hour":"03:00"
"hour":"01:00"
"hour":"08:00"
},

{"prop":"C",
 "hour":"04:00"
 "hour":"12:00"
 "hour":"08:12"
 "hour":"04:00"
 },
 ]
```

How can I do that ? I mean extracting similar keys and compact all similar keys into one array of values???

And if it is importtant , here is my back-end in PHP :

```
   if($result = $db->query($sql)){
    $hours = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $drid = $row->id;
        $hour = $row->b_h;
        $matid = $row->mid;
        $month = $row->b_m;
        $day = $row->b_d;
        $hours[] = [
            'prop'=>$drid.'-'.$matid.'-'.$month.'-'.$day,
            'hour'=>$hour
        ];
    }


    echo (json_encode($hours)) ;

}
```

*numbers are not real and I changed my real **prop's** to A B C for simplicity*

And if it helps , later on , I want use each prop in a ng-repeat in angular js to be like this :

```
 <li ng-repeat="hour in propA">hour</li>
```

OR :

```
 <li ng-repeat="hour in propB">hour</li>
```

thanks

Comment: You should post your real array; array keys in php are unique.

Comment: Please post the code you tried and explain your difficulties.

Comment: I posted my real array here , pleassse heeeelp

Answer (score 0):

Edited to fit changed question

```
var doctors =       [
  {"prop":"A","hour":"08:00"},
  {"prop":"A","hour":"08:10"},
  {"prop":"A","hour":"08:20"},
  {"prop":"A","hour":"08:30"},
  {"prop":"A","hour":"08:40"},
  {"prop":"A","hour":"08:50"},
  {"prop":"B","hour":"09:00"},
  {"prop":"B","hour":"09:10"},
  {"prop":"B","hour":"09:20"},
  {"prop":"C","hour":"10:00"},
  {"prop":"C","hour":"10:10"}       ];


var doctors_morph = {};
for(var i in doctors) {
    if(typeof doctors_morph[doctors[i].prop] == 'undefined') {
        doctors_morph[doctors[i].prop] = [];
    }
    doctors_morph[doctors[i].prop].push(doctors[i].hour);

}
```

That way you can access a doctor in way:

```
doctors_morph['A'];
doctors_morph['B'];
doctors_morph['C'];
```

Your Example result will look like:

```
doctors_morph = {
'A' : {
        ['8:00','8:10','8:20','8:30','8:40','8:50']
    }
// etc
}
```

AS for PHP, to skip above you can use:

```
if($result = $db->query($sql)){
    $doctors = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $drid = $row->id;
        $hour = $row->b_h;
        $matid = $row->mid;
        $month = $row->b_m;
        $day = $row->b_d;

        if(!isset($doctors[$drid.'-'.$matid.'-'.$month.'-'.$day]) OR !is_array($doctors[$drid.'-'.$matid.'-'.$month.'-'.$day]))
            $doctors[$drid.'-'.$matid.'-'.$month.'-'.$day] = array();

        $doctors[$drid.'-'.$matid.'-'.$month.'-'.$day][] = $hour;

    }


    echo (json_encode($doctors)) ;

}
```

Comment: Still unanswerable. Object you want as a result has 2 properties. prop and hour. But hour is again not unique.
Also, u want to reorder it in javascript or php language?

Comment: I does not matter
either JS or PHP , 
SO how can I do this / ? I mean I should change my php code to what ?